# how do I console.log the url of the api call using node/express

Tags: node.js, api, express, http

Hi I am using the Moviedb Api and I am having trouble using and integer movie_id path, I would like to see the actual http request that is being made so I can see what is actually getting called here is the code, I am using Node.js and Express Middleware

```
searchRouter.get("/:movieId", (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('reached')
  request({
    uri: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/" + req.params.movieId + "?",
    qs: {
      api_key: secret,
      language: "en-US",
    },
  }).pipe(res);
});
```

I think the problem is that the integer movieId is being translated into string automatically, but I would need to see the actual request in http form to know how to go further, Thank you so much

Comment: Why not assign the URL to a variable and log it *before* putting it in the object? Or assign and log the whole object? Note request is deprecated now.

Comment: I dont know how to do that I just tried const reqq =  request.uri, but nothing came out

Comment: @jonrsharpe, thank you so much I just figured out how to do it, btw you mentioned that request is deprecated, what is the current syntax to be used